# CMake target_sources with `FILE_SET` not providing correct include directory?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm playing with "new" functionality for `target_sources` the `FILE_SET`.

I have a library defined as follows:

```
project(sockets)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME})
add_library(my_project::${PROJECT_NAME} ALIAS ${PROJECT_NAME})

target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        FILE_SET HEADERS
        BASE_DIRS include
        FILES
            include/sockets/socket.hpp
            include/sockets/zmq_socket.hpp
)

target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
        src/zmq_socket.cpp
)
```

My understanding of the documentation (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html#command:target_sources) is that `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` is automatically populated with the `BASE_DIRS` that I have provided to first `target_sources` command.

But than when I have a second library:

```
project(sender)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME})

target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
        src/sender_pimpl.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
        my_project::sockets
)
```

The include file cannot be resolved:

```
/home/pmac/projects/xxxxxxx/src/sender_pimpl.hpp:10:10: fatal error: sockets/socket.hpp: No such file or directory
   10 | #include "sockets/socket.hpp"
```

Looking also at the command line the `-I` parameter for this folder is missing.

Do I need to specify yet again `target_include_directories` - my understanding was that `HEADERS` was supposed to do it automatically? Or is there anything missing in my implementation that stops it

I'm using cmake version 3.25.2

Comment: You can always check which directories are included with `get_target_property(HMESSAGE ${TARGET__NAME} INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message(STATUS "Include Directories for your_target_name: ${HMESSAGE}")`. What do you get?